# Keep items in list when changing activity android

Tags: android

I am developing a sort of calendar app for Android. In my event-list activity i have an `ActionBar` which shows a drop down list with different date intervals. When i choose a date interval from the dropdown list the list fragment reloads the events from an internet server. Fine so far.

The problem i am having is that when i select an event i go inte the detail activity, and when i return from this detail activity to the list, the list is refreshing itself again. How can i prevent the list fragment from getting the events from the internet again?

Comment: Don't forget about December ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass your data in Bundle. Or pass any flag in Bundle. Or put your data in DB to avoid refreshing to often. Or use SharedPreferences to store some kind of flag...

Comment: Definitely - Pass a bundle or store in SQLite.